# UK visitor Visa while traveling in a different country than resident country

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I'm planning to visit the UK next February, and I'm currently in Serbia, soon to travel to Bosnia. I'm a Sri Lankan citizen, and I will be in Bosnia for tourism with visa-free entry, and without a residence visa.

The UK Visa application indicates (although not directly) that I *can* apply for the visa from a different. I am trying to get my bank to post a bank statement to my address in Bosnia, and I can get other supporting documents in order as well.

My questions is would I be able to apply for the UK Visa from a different country than my residence country. I hold a multi-enter long term Schengen visa which allows me visa-free entry to Bosnia. From the gov.uk web site, it is not 100% clear that a person without a residence can apply for a UK visa from any country.

My major concern would be about the bank statement because it will be from a Sri Lankan bank. The statement will include phone numbers and other ways to contact the bank if the consulate wants to contact them, and signed/stamped by them too.

Would it help if I provide a cover letter indicating why I'm applying from Bosnia? I will be speaking at a conference in UK, and I have another conference a couple weeks before the UK one in Brussels, which makes it difficult for me to visit Brussels, go to my home country Sri Lanka, apply for a UK visa and then travel to UK.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply for a UK visitor visa while visiting another country. Section 28 of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk states:

“ 28. An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application. An application for an entry clearance as a visitor or as a short-term student must be made to any post designated by the Secretary of State to accept such applications.”

The latest data on processing times for applications submitted in Sarajevo shows an average of 10 days (May 2019). https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/sarajevo-bosnia-and-herzegovinia/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less